# XML-RPC falult in wordpress site

Tags: xml-rpc

I'm trying to connect my wordpress site with Integromat and an error shown as (Error 200: XML-RPC fault: XML-RPC services are disabled on this site.). When I test my site address with /xmlrpc.php in the end, it show (XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only). Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you possibly supply some relevant example code?

Comment: Thank you for your question ForeverZer0. To be honest, I'm not writing any code in my wordpress site. I go to Integromat website and create account then I create a new scenarios. When I try to create a new scenarios, I try to connect with my wordpress site and the above error was shown.

Answer (score 0):

If xml-rpc is enabled, you can use the old version of WordPress. You may want to try to disable all plugins and attempt a login. Also, you should just do a quick check to see if you've followed all the steps outlined in the support documentation: https://support.integromat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023690974-WordPress